# Why can't download subtitle with pure python?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, subtitle

Download the subtitle with youtube-dl command:

```
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix8xPfKDxNg"
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --skip-download --sub-lang en  $url
[info] Writing video subtitles to: Speak English Confidently & Clearly with Ellen-Ix8xPfKDxNg.en.vtt
```

Now i want to do the same task with pure python code.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix8xPfKDxNg"
options = {
        'writeautomaticsub': True,
        'subtitleslangs': ['en'],
        'skip_download': True,
        'subtitleslangs': 'en'
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

The error info:

```
WARNING: e subtitles not available for Ix8xPfKDxNg
WARNING: n subtitles not available for Ix8xPfKDxNg
```

Why can't replace the bash command

```
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --skip-download --sub-lang en  $url
```

with pure python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the following should fix it for you, `'subtitleslangs': 'en'`. As you have already included it in as `'subtitleslangs': ['en']`

```
options = {
        'writeautomaticsub': True,
        'subtitleslangs': ['en'],
        'skip_download': True
}
```

`subtitleslang`s needs to be included within `[]`.

I also found adding the option to list all the available options `'listsubtitles': True` then adding the `subtitleslangs` after helps too.